# Error creating react application > Git commit not created Error: Command failed: git commit -m "Initialize project using Create React App"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, git, yarnpkg

I am a Windows user and I have yarn, node js, git, npm installed. In the part when I create my react application with the command npx create-react-app my-app starts to create but almost at the end I mark this error:

```
PS C:\React> npx create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in C:\React\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.12: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.12" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.1.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 13 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ cra-template@1.0.3
├─ react-dom@16.13.1
├─ react-scripts@3.4.1
└─ react@16.13.1
info All dependencies
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types@7.9.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-runtime@7.9.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-typescript@7.9.4
├─ @babel/preset-typescript@7.9.0
├─ babel-preset-react-app@9.1.2
├─ cra-template@1.0.3
├─ eslint-config-react-app@5.2.1
├─ react-dev-utils@10.2.1
├─ react-dom@16.13.1
├─ react-error-overlay@6.0.7
├─ react-scripts@3.4.1
├─ react@16.13.1
└─ scheduler@0.19.1
Done in 19.76s.

Initialized a git repository.

Installing template dependencies using yarnpkg...
yarn add v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.1.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.12: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.12" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
warning " > @testing-library/user-event@7.2.1" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=5".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 20 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ @testing-library/jest-dom@4.2.4
├─ @testing-library/react@9.5.0
├─ @testing-library/user-event@7.2.1
├─ react-dom@16.13.1
└─ react@16.13.1
info All dependencies
├─ @babel/runtime-corejs3@7.9.2
├─ @sheerun/mutationobserver-shim@0.3.3
├─ @testing-library/dom@6.16.0
├─ @testing-library/jest-dom@4.2.4
├─ @testing-library/react@9.5.0
├─ @testing-library/user-event@7.2.1
├─ @types/prop-types@15.7.3
├─ @types/react-dom@16.9.6
├─ @types/react@16.9.34
├─ @types/testing-library__dom@7.0.1
├─ @types/testing-library__react@9.1.3
├─ css.escape@1.5.1
├─ csstype@2.6.10
├─ dom-accessibility-api@0.3.0
├─ min-indent@1.0.0
├─ react-dom@16.13.1
├─ react@16.13.1
├─ redent@3.0.0
├─ strip-indent@3.0.0
└─ wait-for-expect@3.0.2
Done in 6.53s.
Removing template package using yarnpkg...

yarn remove v1.22.4
[1/2] Removing module cra-template...
[2/2] Regenerating lockfile and installing missing dependencies...
info fsevents@2.1.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.12: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.12" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
warning " > @testing-library/user-event@7.2.1" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=5".
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
success Uninstalled packages.
Done in 5.67s.
Git commit not created Error: Command failed: git commit -m "Initialize project using Create React App"
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:630:11)
    at execSync (child_process.js:666:15)
    at tryGitCommit (C:\React\my-app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\init.js:62:5)
    at module.exports (C:\React\my-app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\init.js:334:25)
    at [eval]:3:14
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:120:20)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:311:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:10:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at evalScript (internal/process/execution.js:94:25) {
  status: 128,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 10420,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}
Removing .git directory...

Success! Created my-app at C:\React\my-app
Inside that directory, you can run several commands:

  yarn start
    Starts the development server.

  yarn build
    Bundles the app into static files for production.

  yarn test
    Starts the test runner.

  yarn eject
    Removes this tool and copies build dependencies, configuration files
    and scripts into the app directory. If you do this, you can’t go back!

We suggest that you begin by typing:

  cd my-app
  yarn start

Happy hacking!
PS C:\React>
```

**Also when I try to lift the react application created I get this error:**

```
PS C:\React> cd .\my-app\
PS C:\React\my-app> yarn start
yarn run v1.22.4
$ react-scripts start
i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.56.1/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\React\my-app\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

events.js:287
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000"' ]
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
PS C:\React\my-app>
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: I just got the same git commit issue with Ubuntu 20.04. But yarn start works fine.

Answer (score 13):

Configure your git identity with:

```
git config --global user.name <yourName>
git config --global user.email <yourEmail>
```

For example you can use your GitHub account data.